# Irregular font size in browsers of certain Android devices

Tags: android, html, css

In the following HTML document:

> http://fiddle.jshell.net/v0yqL8xp/show/

When running on an Android device> = 8 and Chrome browser (79.03945.116), I find the following problem related to font size (font-size: 16px;):
The two div of the .medium class reduce the text compared to the .large class
If I increase the size of the .medium class to 100%, the text returns to the correct size.

Has anyone had any similar problems?

> HTML y CSS: http://jsfiddle.net/v0yqL8xp/

**Snippet:**

```css
*
{
 padding: 0;
 margin: 0;
}


.medium
{
 float: left;
 width: 50%;
}

.large
{
 width: 100%;
}

p
{
 text-align: justify;
 font-size: 16px;
 padding: 14px;
}
```

```html
<div class="medium">
 <p>Fugiat sit et tempor magna adipisicing excepteur veniam. Velit reprehenderit amet do et sint officia Lorem esse irure eiusmod consectetur. Laboris esse duis enim dolore et ex aliqua proident ullamco id ullamco nostrud amet. Qui culpa ad sint adipisicing do cillum velit proident exercitation ipsum. Pariatur reprehenderit reprehenderit elit irure ea cupidatat labore minim. Labore qui est minim occaecat commodo minim consectetur id aliquip. Sit veniam excepteur cupidatat eiusmod.</p>
</div>

<div class="medium">
 <p>Fugiat sit et tempor magna adipisicing excepteur veniam. Velit reprehenderit amet do et sint officia Lorem esse irure eiusmod consectetur. Laboris esse duis enim dolore et ex aliqua proident ullamco id ullamco nostrud amet. Qui culpa ad sint adipisicing do cillum velit proident exercitation ipsum. Pariatur reprehenderit reprehenderit elit irure ea cupidatat labore minim. Labore qui est minim occaecat commodo minim consectetur id aliquip. Sit veniam excepteur cupidatat eiusmod.</p>
</div>

<div class="large">
 <p>Fugiat sit et tempor magna adipisicing excepteur veniam. Velit reprehenderit amet do et sint officia Lorem esse irure eiusmod consectetur. Laboris esse duis enim dolore et ex aliqua proident ullamco id ullamco nostrud amet. Qui culpa ad sint adipisicing do cillum velit proident exercitation ipsum. Pariatur reprehenderit reprehenderit elit irure ea cupidatat labore minim. Labore qui est minim occaecat commodo minim consectetur id aliquip. Sit veniam excepteur cupidatat eiusmod.</p>
</div>
```

**Here you can see how the size of the letter of div 1 and 2 is smaller than that of the third**

[image: xd]